# SOQL Limit Exceptions

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

Below is my code

```
        for(object__c conv: database.query(query)){
            List <Attachment> attachmentList = [SELECT Id, Name, ContentType, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :conv.Id limit 1];  
            if (attachmentList.size() > 0){
                Attachment att = attachmentList[0];
                row.AttachmentId = att.Id;
                row.AttachmentName = att.Name;
                row.AttachmentType = att.ContentType;
            }
```

This Code gives me the

> Too Many SOQL Queries 101 exception

so I have updated it as below

```
        list <Attachment> attachmentList = [select Id, Name, ParentId from Attachment];
        for(object__c conv: database.query(query)){  
            for (Attachment att : attachmentList){
                if (conv.Id == att.ParentId){
                    row.AttachmentId = att.Id;
                    row.AttachmentName = att.Name;
                    row.AttachmentType = att.ContentType;
                }
            }
```

but this code gives me below error

> exceeded 100000 distinct ids

What can I do to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do like this

first query the object and store into list

```
List<object__c>  lstconv = database.query(query);
```

after that based on this list only get only their attachments

```
list <Attachment> attachmentList = [select Id, Name, ParentId 
                                      from Attachment WHERE ParentId IN: lstconv];
```

after that iterate over the attachment and create `row` (don't know what it is)

```
for (Attachment att : attachmentList)
{
    row.AttachmentId = att.Id;
    row.AttachmentName = att.Name;
    row.AttachmentType = att.ContentType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub-query in your SOQL, which has a distinct advantage of memory usage and processing time. Here's what that would look like:

```
for(Object__c parentRecord: [SELECT (SELECT Name, ContentType FROM Attachments) FROM Object__c) {
  for(Attachment attachmentRecord: parentRecord.Attachments) {
    row.AttachmentId = attachmentRecord.Id;
    row.AttachmentName = attachmentRecord.Name;
    row.AttachmentType = attachmentRecord.ContentType;
  }
}
```

Note that you don't need to check if a list is empty before you iterate over it; this code would work just fine if the `Object__c` were updated to the name of object you're using.